# Is it possible to use Mysql in a visual studio project with linq syntax?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

In an attempt to add a DB to my visual studio Project I chose mysql and got a little confused in the process of adding the db.
after three days of research with trial and error I ended up downloading the /net mysql connector and mysql for visual studio. I was able to set up a connection to the db and even perform some queries using a string in a MySqlCommand type
 (e.g. MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from jobs")  )

my ultimate objective though is using linq syntax for the queries , is that possible?
and if so,is there a simple guide or a code example? 
(tried looking for one myself with little to no success)

Comment: [Using MySQL with Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and what I use for most of my work. Like Habib has commented, you need to use MySQL with Entity Framework. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework) article.